# python Beginner : class

Tags: python-3.x

Can someone please help me/show me how to fix this code ?
I'm getting an error:

> TypeError: get_color() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'self' and 'color'

```
class Automobile:
    def __init__(self, color):
        self.color = color

    def get_color(self, color):
        input("Enter number")
        if self.color == 1:
           print("white")

def main():
   Automobile.get_color()
main()
```

Comment: Please edit your question to indicate what's actually wrong with it. Just as a guess your indentation looks incorrect.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have marked down teh error by using a leading >

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to instantiate an object of your class. And using this you can call `get_color()`.

```
auto = Automobile(1)
auto.get_color()
```

Also consider rewriting your `get_color` to:

```
def get_color(self):
    if self.color == 1:
        return "white"
    else:
        return "none"
```

As your current implementation doesn't really do what you'd expect a function named `get_color` to do.

Comment: What if i wanted to add more colors?

Comment: So you want your automobile to have multiple colors?

Comment: I want to prompt the user to enter  the numbers (1,2 or 3) and depending on their selection it outputs the color that it was assigned to

Comment: You do that outside of your class, your class shouldn't contain logic like that, it should simply just be a container that you operate on.

Answer (score 1):

From how I read your code, it looks like you're trying to make your get_x method do what a set_x method typically does. Also, based on your code having

```
if self.color == 1:
print(white)
```

I think you want to map 1 to white, and then maybe 2 to black, 3 to blue, and so on?

I'll deal with the last part first. Typically, if you want to map something to something else (in this case, a number to a color), you are best off using a dictionary:

```
color_dict = {1: 'white',
              2: 'black',
              3: 'etc.',}
```

Then, you can call (for example) white by writing

```
>>>print(color_dict[1])
'white'
```

Now, on the class, I will show you two different approaches to do what (I think) you want to do.

Option A: Old-School getter/setters:

```
class Automobile:
def __init__(self, color):
    self.color_dict = {1: 'white',
                       2: 'black',
                       3: 'etc.',}

    self.color = self.color_dict[key]

def get_color(self):
    return self.color

def set_color(self, key):
    self.color = self.color_dict[color]
```

from here, then, you can call:

```
>>>auto = Automobile(1)
>>>print(auto.get_color())
'white'
>>>auto.set_color(2)
>>>auto.print(auto.get_color())
'black'
```

This will work great, and I think it does what you'd like.

There's a newer approach in python 3, but it uses decorators (you'll see in a second, they start with '@', and they're kind of hard to understand)

Option B: New-style property-based approach

```
class Automobile:
    def __init__(self, color):
        self.color_dict = {1: 'white',
                           2: 'black',
                           3: 'etc.',}

        self.color = color

    @property
    def color(self):
        return self._color

    @color.setter
    def color(self, key):
        self._color = self.color_dict[key]
```

The usage is a little different here.  It starts the same:

```
>>>auto = Automobile(1)
>>>print(auto.color)
'white'
```

But then, to change the color, instead of using a function, you modify the property with =

```
>>>auto.color = 2
>>>print(auto.color)
'black'
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

By typing `Automobile.get_color()` you are telling the class itself Automobile to tell you its color.

However, `Automobile` as a class doesn't have a color!

A class is a blueprint or a plan of values and functions for **Instances** of that class to expand upon. For example, you would need to say:

`NissanLeaf = Automobile(2)`
in order to say that you have a Black Nissan Leaf.

Then, you can go `NissanLeaf.get_color()` in order to find out that the car is indeed black.

An **Instance**, in other words, is an actual creation built by using the **Class** as a blueprint. In order to see an attribute of an object, it needs to be an actual creation and not just the idea of it.

You can make an Instance of an object by putting parentheses after the class name and then filling the parentheses with any parameters you set in the `__init__` function of the class.

For example:

```
class Human:
    def __init__(self, age, height):
        self.age = age
        self.height = height
```

Is the blueprint and

```
John = Human(27, 71)
```

Is the Instance of the class Human, from which we can

```
print John.age
>>> 27
```

Retrieve data.

Hope that helped!!!